# Is it possible to avoid using type checking in this example?

Tags: java, interface, typechecking

Sorry for the poor title, can't think of a succinct way of putting this..

I'm thinking of having a list of objects that will all be of a specific interface. Each of these objects may then implement further interfaces, but there is no guarantee which object will implement which. However, in a single loop, I wish to be able to call the methods of whatever their further sub-type may be.

Ie, 3 interfaces:

```
public interface IAnimal { ... }
public interface IEggLayer { public Egg layEgg(); }
public interface IMammal { public void sweat(); }
```

this would then be stored as

```
private List<IAnimal> animals= new ArrayList<IAnimal>();
```

so, instances added to the list could possibly also be of type `IEggLayer` or `IMammal`, which have completely unrelated methods.

My initial instinct would be to then do

```
for(IAnimal animal : animals) {
  if(animal instanceof IEggLayer) {
    egg = ((IEggLayer)animal).layEgg();
  }
  if(animal instance of IMammal) {
    ((IMammal)animal).sweat();
  }
}
```

But I have always been told that type checking is a sign that the code should really be refactored.

Since it could be possible for a single object to do both [platypus, for example], meaning that a single `doFunction()` would not be suitable here, is it possible to avoid using type checking in this case, or is this an instance where type checking is classed as acceptable?
Is there possibly a design pattern catered to this?

I apologise for the contrived example as well...
[Ignore any syntax errors, please - it's only intended to be Java-like pseudocode]

I've added lvalue to the EggLayer use, to show that sometimes the return type is important

Comment: this code appears to be java, why the C# flag?

Comment: because someone else added it. I' may remove the java tag that's been added too, as I'm hoping to keep this language independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I have always been told that type checking is a sign that the code should really be refactored.

It is a sign that either class hierarchy or the code that uses it *may* need to be refactored or restructured.  But often there will be no refactoring / restructuring that avoids the problem.

In this case, where you have methods that apply only to specific subtypes, the most promising refactor would be to have separate lists for the animals that are egg layers and the animals that sweat.

But if you cannot do that, you will need to do some type checking.  Even the `isEggLayer()` / `isMammal()` involves a type check; e.g.

```
if (x.isEggLayer()) {
    ((IEggLayer) x).layEgg();  // type cast is required.
}
```

I suppose that you could hide the type check via an `asEggLayer()` method; e.g.

```
public IEggLayer asEggLayer() {
    return ((IEggLayer) this);
}
```

or

```
// Not recommended ...
public IEggLayer asEggLayer() {
    return (this instanceof IEggLayer) ? ((IEggLayer) this) : null;
}
```

But there is always a typecheck happening, and the possibility that it will fail.  Furthermore, all of these attempts to hide the type checking entail adding "knowledge" of the subtypes to the supertype interface, which means that it needs to be changed as new subtypes are added.

Comment: By the way, there are mammals that lay eggs.

Comment: "In this case, where you have methods that apply only to specific subtypes, the most promising refactor would be to have separate lists for the animals that are egg layers and the animals that sweat."
I think this is sort of the way I'm going to have to go, the further interfaces should be able to be made mutually exclusive in some way - the interfaces are going to have as few methods as possible...

Comment: and yes, I know that - which is why I specifically picked these interfaces for the example [and mentioned the platypus in the question]

Answer (score 5):

Clearly your `IAnimal` interface (or some extension thereof) needs a `callAllMethods` method that each implementer of the interface can code to polymorphically perform this task -- seems the only OO-sound approach!

Comment: I can see where this is coming from, but unfortunately I don't think it will work for me as in some cases I may need to rely on objects that the method calls return [of specific types], and in other cases I won't and it makes no sense for the method to have a non-void return type

Comment: Nevertheless, each case where processing is type-dependent must be coded within the type (or nested classes thereof), if you want to claim you're doing Java OOP; so these different "some cases" / "other cases" must be present as methods on the interface.

Comment: I like this--we can surely come up with a better name, though. "liveAnotherDay()" or something...

Comment: If, in some cases, it makes no sense to have a non-void return type, couldn't you just use a Nullable type as the return type, and return null in those cases? The type-checking method essentially works the same way, it just leaves variable (like 'egg') as null in these cases, rather than explicitly setting them to null.

Comment: @TR, good point -- the existence of `null` as a possible return value for functions declared with almost any type sure helps you out here.

Answer (score 1):

in C#, you should be able to do this transparently.

```
foreach(IEggLayer egglayer in animals) {
    egglayer.layEgg();
}

foreach(IMammal mammal in animals) {
    mammal.sweat();
}
```

Comment: Except he is using java it appears, from the for loop syntax.

Comment: unfortunately I'm working in Java, which as far as Ican make out, doesn't work - type mismatching

Comment: Looks like C# with all the Iungarian notation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to think about this question is: What is the loop doing? The loop has a purpose and is trying to do something with those objects. That something can have a method on the IAnimal interface, and the implementations can sweat or lay eggs as needed.

In terms of your issue with the return value, you will be returning null, nothing you can do about that if you share the methods. It is not worth casting within a loop to avoid an extra return null; to satisfy the compiler. You can, however, make it more explicit using generics:

```
  public interface IAnimal<R> {

         public R generalMethod();

  }

  public interface IEggLayer extends IAnimal<Egg> {

         public Egg generalMethod(); //not necessary, but the point is it works.

  }

  public interface IMammal extends IAnimal<Void> {

        public Void generalMethod();

  }
```

From your comment where you care about the return type, you can get the return type and dispatch it to a factory method which examines the type and returns something generic that is sublcassed to the specific type and act on that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have methods added to isAnimal:

```
public interface IAnimal {
   bool isEggLayer();
   bool isMammal();
}
```

Then you can loop through and just query this boolean each time.

**Update:**
If this was drawing an animal, then having a class that is completely enclosed is reasonable, you just call `drawVehicle` and it draws a corvette, cessna, motorcycle, whatever.

But, this seems to have a non-OOP architecture, so if the architecture of the application can't change then, since my original answer isn't well received, then it would seem that AOP would be the best choice.

If you put an annotation on each class, you can have

```
@IsEggLayer
@IsMammal
public class Platypus() implements EggLayer, Mammal {
...
}
```

This would then enable you to create aspects that pull out all the egglayers and do whatever operations need to be done.

You can also inject into the animal interfaces any additional classes to get this idea to work.

I will need to think about where to go from here, but I have a feeling this may be the best solution, if a redesign can't be done.

Comment: mainly because this would mean needing to change IAnimal and all its implementations everytime that I add a type with new functionality, as opposed to creating the new ADT and only needing to add the check into the loop.

Comment: No real advantage wrt doing the typechecking outside -- still breaks the core principles of OOP (here, the interface, as well as the calling code, must BOTH know about all possible groups of implementations, so it's arguably even worse).

Comment: I'm not sure if not well received is what I intended with my comment. More that the original answer was pretty much changing one form of type checking for another, which as far as I can tell would involve more maintenance when new interfaces and functionality are introduced

Comment: Which is why AspectJ could simplify the maintenance, and Alex was correct, my solution violates OOP principles, but this solution doesn't seem to be designed to be following these principles, so, given the architecture, AOP gives an out, so that each class doesn't need to have information is doesn't need, such as a dog class being an egglayer being set to false.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of going about this. Exaclty which is most appropriate depends upon your context. I am going to suggest introducing an additional layer of indirection. This solves most problems. I prefer designs which avoid multiple inheritance of interface (if I were president of a language, I would forbid it).

I don't think `layEggsOrSweatOrDoBothIfYoureWeirdOrNoneIfYouCant()` is a great method to polute `Animal` with. So instead of adding each `Animal` directly to `animals`, wrap each in an individual wrapper. I say "wrapper" as a generic name - the random operation we are trying to perform doesn't make any sense.

```
private final List<AnimalWrapper> animals =
    new ArrayList<AnimalWrapper>();

public void doStuff() {
    for (AnimalWrapper animal : animals) {
        animal.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Then we need some way of adding the wrappers. Something like:

```
public void addPlatypus(final Platypus platypus) {
    animals.add(new AnimalWrapper() { public void doYourStuff() {
        platypus.sweat();
        platypus.layEgg();
    }});
}
```

If you try to write these wrappers without enough context you get into trouble. These require that the correct one is selected at call site. It could be done by overloading, but that has dangers.

```
/*** Poor context -> trouble ***/

public void addNormalMamal(final Mamal mamal) {
    animals.add(new AnimalWrapper() { public void doYourStuff() {
        mamal.sweat();
    }});
}
public void addNormalEggLayer(final EggLayer eggLayer) {
    animals.add(new AnimalWrapper() { public void doYourStuff() {
        eggLayer.layEgg();
    }});
}
public <T extends Mamal & EggLayer> void addMamalEggLayer(final T animal) {
    animals.add(new AnimalWrapper() { public void doYourStuff() {
        animal.sweat();
        animal.layEgg();
    }});
}
```